# suitescript run a function on a button click

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Redux:
I want run a Script on a button click (because you cannot run a function in your script ona  button click) I've followed the Suitescript documentation and am only able to get the second log to run. Any idea?

```
` form.setScript('customscript_toloader')
 form.addButton('custpagetestbutton', 'TEST button', 'createTO();');`
```

-Other script

```
function createTO() //(request, response)
{   
alert("This function was called");
//variable set up
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'script', 'runs 1');
    var POID ;
    var POType ;
    var PORecord;
    var lines;
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'script', 'runs 2');
    var arrayName = new Array();
    var arrayQty = new Array();
    PORecord = nlapiGetNewRecord();
    lines = PORecord.getLineItemCount('item');
    POID = nlapiGetRecordId();
    POTYPE = nlapiGetRecordType();
    // get name and quantity
    for ( var i = 1; i < lines + 1 ; i++ )
    {
        arrayName[i] = PORecord.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', i ); 
        arrayQty[i] = PORecord.getLineItemValue('item', 'quantity' , i);
    }
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'script', 'runs 3');

    //creates to and changes focus
    var TOrecord = nlapiCreateRecord ('transferorder');
    var TOrecordID = TOrecord.getId();
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('customform',128);
    //subsidiaries CC bedford id is 2
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('subsidiary',2);
    //testing for location and transfer location, 144 & 145
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('location',144);
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('transferlocation',145);
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('memo', 'PO: ' + POID );
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('employee',nlapiGetContext().getUser());
    //TOrecord.setFieldValue('department',"C-C");

    //set name and quantity
    for ( var j = 1; j < lines +1  ; j++ )
    {
        arrayName[j] = parseInt(arrayName[j]); 
        TOrecord.setLineItemValue("item", "item", j , arrayName[j] );
        TOrecord.setLineItemValue("item", "quantity", j , parseInt(arrayQty[j])); //added parse int, should work

    }


    // set the item and location values on the currently selected line
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'location', 6);
    // commit the line to the database
    //nlapiCommitLineItem('item');

    var TOResult = nlapiSubmitRecord(TOrecord, true, true);
    var TOTranID= nlapiLookupField('transferorder', TOResult, 'tranid');
    var poURL = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD', 'transferorder', TOResult);

    nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD','transferorder', TOResult);
    return;
     }
```

~rest of the code that does not execute~`

Answer (score 2):

> var steve = "form.setScript('customscript_toloader')" ; 
>   form.addButton('custpage_purchaseorder', 'Create TO', steve);

Not sure what you're trying to do in these lines but the third param in the addButton should just be your function name. For example:

form.addButton('custpage_purchaseorder', 'Create TO', 'createTO');

Comment: suitescript is weird. Doing that would cause the function to run on load, not when the button is pressed.

Comment: Are you sure it is running on load?  I have use it multiple times and it never runs on load for me, only when the button is clicked.  Maybe you call calling the same function for the button in your Before Load function.

Comment: It will run whatever argument is put into the button on before load.
The only exception i have found is by putting a string script in the argument and then it will work on button click. But doing that for my function causes it not to run at all.
`var steve = "function test() {alert('Button was clicked from ' + nlapiGetRecordType() + ' in VIEW mode');\
     var hi= 'hello';\
     alert(hi) ;}test()";`